# Correct definition of Class Members

Tags: php, oop, function

I'm really new to programming especially OOP and I wonder how I can write this kind of functions correctly?

Is there a best practice? Maybe it depends on the readability of the code but I have no idea which is better? Personally I would prefer the third one but i want to learn the "correct" way...

```
// Version #1
public function getUser( $id )
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
    $user = $this->database->query($sql);
    return $user;
}

// Version #2    
public function getUser( $id )
{
    $user = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id");
    return $user;
}

// Version #3    
public function getUser( $id )
{
    return $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id");
}
```

Comment: though its oftopic and php only supports for objects and arrays, take a look at typehinting: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: As far as i know type hinting works only for objects and arrays... But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of them are wrong because you didn't sanitize `$id`, if it's meant to be an int, the first line of your function should be:

```
$id = (int) $id;
```

if it's anything else it should be:

```
$id = $this->database->whateveryourescapefunctioniscalled($id);
```

Now, to your real question. 1 and 2 have the advantage that, if your database function returns something other than a user (some functions return false on failure), you have some way to handle it in this function. In #3, you have to handle it wherever you call `getUser`. This will turn into a mess. If your query ever gets longer (requiring joins, etc) you'll probably want something more like 1 but until then, 2 is fine. Even 3 is fine if you don't care or don't need to handle failed query cases here.

Comment: In addition you can use `filter_var()` to sanitize your `$id` - http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Ah, this is an interesting function. I've never seen it before.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the three examples, there is not much to be said in terms of OOP. You should understand what the IDEA of CLASS is. A class is revolves around a central concept, or idea or subject. Then, class fields are those attributes that describe that subject. For example, if you have a class that represents a point in a coordinate system, then attributes of x and y coordinates are natural attributes of that class. What I am trying to say is that, object-orientation is based on certain principles (which many seem to miss). It is not about writing some code in two line vs one line.

Comment: I know about the concept of classes and inheritance. It's on an example. I'm looking for best practices to write Methods (class members). As you can see it is 3 Times the same funtion but with a different notation.

Comment: Look, you should not down vote without providing a reason. I was trying to help you see that you were not clear about things that you were asking. Again, look at your original question. Its title says "Correct definition of class members", and then you go on and ask about how to write a piece of code. These are two totally different things.